# Where to define worker inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am writing a gem. I would like the calls to the gem's api to trigger calls to some Sidekiq workers. Where do I write these workers inside my gem so Sidekiq finds them even though they are not in 'app/workers'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without knowing exactly what you are doing.

However I'd say that adding a procfile that people installing your gem can use would work.

Ref https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Comment: Hello marcgg, thank you for your answer. My gem is supposed to do async queries to another webservice. So I would like this work to be done in a Sidekiq worker and any application willing to make use of the gem could simply call the api without having to worry about creating workers, the gem would take care of that.